# Laravel Выборка записей из БД с пробелом

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, выборка

В базе хранится запись Мобильные телефоны. Так вот, при выборке и подстановке в атрибут value Ларавель оборачивает первое слово в кавычки - "Мобильные", а слово телефоны игнорирует. Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию, ибо мне по этой записи нужно в дальнейшем делать другую выборку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выборка:

```
 $category = DB::table('category')->get();
```

Подстановка значений:

```
@foreach($category as $c)
            <li>
                <form action="{{url("/selectProduct")}}" method="post">
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="categoryName" value= {{$c->name}}>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
            </li>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Должно выводить в том виде, в котором оно есть. Проверьте значение $c->name. И подстановку делайте value="{{$c->name}}"

Comment: Блин, спасибо. Про кавычки забыл в value. Теперь выводит как нужно) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение атрибута `value` нужно заключить в кавычки:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="categoryName" value="{{$c->name}}">
```